# Profibus-DP interface & library for Arduino/Pi?

Tags: arduino, serial-port, raspberry-pi, rs485

I'm somewhat stuck with a prob: I have a measuring-transducer Profibus-DP Master-device here that reads probe-values (eg. temperature) and I need to get those values into a Pi or Arduino. The Device is able to do Profibus-DP, PA and Hart.

I am right that there is no finished library and hardware for that? I've found industrial grade ICs like [this](http://profichip.com/products/overviewasics/dp-slave-vpc3-s/) and [opensource stuff](https://static.lwn.net/images/conf/rtlws11/papers/proc/p29.pdf) that quickly got lawsuited and a [shield for RS-485](https://www.cooking-hacks.com/documentation/tutorials/rs-485-module-shield-tutorial-for-arduino-raspberry-pi-intel-galileo/).  But even that shield wouldn't help me to actually communicate, right? I still would need to figure out all the protocoll-basics, timing and stuff?